# How do I change the product key for Microsoft Office 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office, license-key

I've been asked to "re-key" my copy of MS Office 2007 to use a different product key.  Is this possible?  If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft offers the answer to this question [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895456).  It applies to earlier versions of Microsoft Office as well.

> - Close all Office programs.
> - Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
> - Locate and then click the following subkey, depending on your version of
>     Windows and of Office:
>
> **32-bit versions**
>
> ```
> 2007 Office system
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Registration
>
> Office 2003 
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Registration
>
> Office XP
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \Software\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Registration
> ```
>
> **64-bit versions**
>
> ```
> 2007 Office system
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Registration
>
> Office 2003
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Registration
>
> Office XP
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Registration
> ```
>
> - Export the Registration subkey
>
>   - You can make a backup of the values under the Registration subkey
>       if the new product key does not work.
>       To do this, follow these steps:
>
>     - Right-click the Registration subkey, and then click Export.
>     - In the Save in list, select a location to save the registration
>         entries.
>     - In the File name box, type a name for the .reg file that you want
>         to export, and then click Save.
> - Under the Registration subkey, there may be several Globally Unique
>     Identifiers (GUID) that contain a
>     combination of alphanumeric
>     characters. Each GUID is specific to a
>     program that is installed on your
>     computer.
>
>   - Click a GUID. Then, view the version of Office that is listed in
>       the right pane for the Productname
>       registry entry. After you find the
>       GUID that contains the version of your
>       Office program, follow these steps:
>
>     - Right-click the DigitalProductID registry entry, click
>         Delete, and then click Yes.
>     - Right-click the ProductID registry entry, click Delete, and then
>         click Yes.
> - Open an Office program, such as Microsoft Word. When you receive a
>     message that prompts you for the
>     product key, type the correct product
>     key, and then click OK.

Comment: +1 Excellent find, I edited your answer to put in the text from the article

Comment: These keys don't exist in Windows 10. The ONLY way to change it is to uninstall Office and reinstall it.

Answer (score -1):

**[Win Keyfinder 1.73 RC2](http://www.winkeyfinder.com/winkeyfinder-news/win-keyfinder-1.73-rc2.php)**

among many other features:

> View/Change MS Office Key
>
> Support for MS Office 2007

Comment: You can't change keys with this program. At least not anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Easy Way: Run this 
[Microsoft Fixit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/0/9/D097A86B-8742-4B09-8236-5D595B435950/MicrosoftFixit50755.msi) and reopen any Office 2007 application. Enter key when prompted

Comment: Fixit is no longer on MS's site nor anywhere on the Internet. Just dead links. Fail.